# How to pass data down to a component via custom directive in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to achieve this kind of behavior

```html
<simple-component v-layer="'pizza'" />
```

Use a custom directive, pass `'pizza'` to the component and being able to use it inside of my `SimpleComponent`.
The idea would be to bring it up in the upper parent scope afterwards (via `v-slot`), it's hacky and probably not the best way to go but the syntax is important for my client (less typed chars being better here).

I found [this github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2238#issuecomment-456711453) for Vue2, but I'm not sure how to make this work for Vue3 or even the syntax (I know it's not `vNode.context` but `binding.instance` now and also, we don't need `$set` since Vue3 is using proxies).

[The documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#directive) doesn't really help me and inspecting the instance in the regular devtools did not gave me any leads.

PS: we can do pretty much anything in `SimpleComponent` itself, we just don't need to see it from the outside of the component.

Comment: What you want is what props are for. Why use directive? Directives are for low level DOM manipulation...

Comment: Yeah I know that props are the use case for this. As I wrote, here I'm looking for a dirty hacky solution but with the least amount of things to write down. I thought a directive would be perfect to "hide" some stuff and do that automatically for the end user. This is bad and ugly, but the end goal would be to have the least possible syntax to write down, especially if it can be guessed ahead of time. So, I thought custom directive + global mixin would be perfect for that use case!

Comment: Sorry I don't get what's better (or shorter) about `v-layer="'pizza'"` over `layer="pizza"`. Anyway it is explicitly documented that all directive hooks arguments except `el` are **read only** - [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#prevnode). So even if you figure out the correct syntax, you are breaking Vue rules

Comment: The thing is that I may add **more** than just the prop, I also saw the warning that it's **read only** yep. As I told you, I know that this is hacky and against the Vue API. I mean, I totally agree on your position here, I share it too. Meanwhile, my client will do it anyway. I prefer to find the best less ugly one by myself.

Comment: You need to be the programmer here and push back against the client.

Comment: Haha, don't worry about that @paddyfields, I'm telling him daily that this is a super bad idea. But trust me, it's better if I do it my way here. Also, this will be heavily documented and deprecated from day1 in our documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

This is hacky, and probably not the way to go because it going against the Vue API (which is clearly saying that it's [**read only**](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#prevnode)), so yeah: you probably don't want to use it that way.

Also, a directive is used for DOM element modifications, not to reach and mutate a Vue state elsewhere. My team's needs are very hacky.
Don't reproduce it at home, use regular props instead.

---

Meanwhile, if you do, here is how.

`page.vue`

```html
<template>
  <simple-div v-layer="'pizza'">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  directives: {
    layer: {
      mounted(_el, binding, vnode) {
        vnode.ref.i.data.layer = binding.value
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`SimpleDiv.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div ref="layerHack">  <!-- this ref is required -->
    <div>{{ layer }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      layer: null,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```